# ASPError object doesn't contain any data on my custom error page

Tags: iis-7, asp-classic, vbscript

I have the following in my **web.config**

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

The error handling is working in that, when a 500 error occurs, I am sent to my `error.asp` instead of the default 500 error page.

The issue is that none of the properties of the `ASPError` object returned by `Server.GetLastError` are set.

For example, in the code below, the error description is

```
dim oErr : set oErr = Server.GetLastError

Response.Write "Error Description:  " & oErr.Description& "<br />"
```

---

#### Update

Based on the thread Joel linked to in the comments, I've updated my web.config to the following:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" />
    <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

This **does** give me data in the ASPError object returned by `GetLastError`.

The issue now is that I'm getting the HTML from the beginning of the page where the error is generated, then the rest of the page is the HTML from `error.asp`.

I'd really like it to redirect to `error.asp` instead but changing the web.config to `responseMode="Redirect"` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Is this thread any help? http://forums.iis.net/t/1150502.aspx

Comment: That definitely gives me a starting point.  I've updated the question with a little more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the solution that's working for me.

Setup up the **web.config** like this:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" />
    <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/error.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
</httpErrors>
```

A simple **error.asp** might look like this:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% 
    Option Explicit
    On Error Resume Next
    Response.Clear
    Dim objError, MessageBody
    Set objError = Server.GetLastError()

    Response.Write objError.ASPCode & "<br />"
    Response.Write objError.Number & "<br />"
    Response.Write objError.Description & "<br />"
%>
```

The key to my problems appears to be having `On Error Resume Next` and `Response.Clear`.

I found the solution on the [Creating Custom ASP Error Pages](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/224070) Microsoft KB article (Q224070).

Comment: For me this worked only when I added 500.100 handler on root level of the server. (I have IIS 7.5)

Comment: Yes, it is absolutely necessary to add the `subStatusCode="100"` in order to receive the `ASPError` object from `Server.GetLastError()` on the custom error page.

Comment: Hi there. I set things like above but now I have problem with `errorMode`. Even if I set it to `DetailedLocalOnly` I can always see on local machine my custom error page.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue now is that I'm getting the HTML from the beginning of the
>   page where the error is generated, then the rest of the page is the
>   HTML from error.asp.

Place a

```
Response.Clear
```

in your custom error page